# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' to 'SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.EmailAddress'

Tags: c#, email, model-view-controller

i'm trying to send email and got this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' to 'SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.EmailAddress'

```
    var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("you@somewhere.com", "My name");//here the error Happens
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.PlainTextContent = message.Body;
        myMessage.HtmlContent= message.Body;
```

Comment: Isn't the error clear enough? You are trying to pass a MailAddress instance when an EmailAddress is required.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto even when I give it an address it still gives the same error `myMessage.From = new MailAddress("mb@gmail.com", "Cooler");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've just made a small typo.

Change

```
myMessage.From = new MailAddress("you@somewhere.com", "My name")
```

to

```
myMessage.From = new EmailAddress("you@somewhere.com", "My name")
                     ^
```

Comment: Had the same issue, Not sure about NeverTrust but I was following the how-to for the 2FA email confirmation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

Answer (score -1):

Error in Send Grid:

> cannot convert from 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' to
> 'string'  WindowsServiceCG

Add Method `EmailAddress` instead of `MailAddress`.

```
SendGridMessage message = new SendGridMessage();
message.AddBcc(new EmailAddress("Your Email Address", "personalization msg"));
```